# symfony hwio, how to enable r_fullprofile in linkedin

Tags: symfony, linkedin-api, hwioauthbundle

I have apps in Linkedin and this apps have r_basicprofile,
r_emailaddress, rw_company_admin and w_share. And I have config owners linkedin

```
        linkedin:
        type:           linkedin
        client_id:      "%linkedin_app_id%"
        client_secret:  "%linkedin_app_secret%"
        scope:          "r_emailaddress"
```

and I dump respons

```
 #response: array:4 [▼
"emailAddress" => "*****@gmail.com"
"formattedName" => "Ivan Shuba"
"id" => "*****"
"pictureUrl" => "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_OCZwJKsgekwl-EEy-125jtryenwltHzrUNawpkjy2tyrcZqgRQa5BFrgoiQuNd6j-C2L-C0j3tuKAu4ABAgBAktAktuAAuKjBAgeV5bp7PMgRswTR8I6sAWDXFn3ZuF2OtJbgBD5pKW"
```

But I need skils in Linkedin, I read for r_fullprofile, but my apps not have this scope. Help please

Comment: That scope is no longer available to the public.  You'd have to sign up to be a LinkedIn partner to access that information:  https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: thanks, I write form for partner. Now wait for answer. I hope I'll get a positive answer

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), Linkedin has limited the open APIs.

**Access to `r_fullprofile` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

The following endpoints are available for general use:

- Profile API — /v1/people/~
- Share API — /v1/people/~/shares
- Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}

If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g. Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search, etc.) you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of the endpoints that are not listed above.

Check out this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) for the list of API changes that were announced.